# Coordinate a randomly chosen turtle and its characteristic

Tags: random, netlogo

I'm trying to build a simple market model, such as what follows.

```
breed [ firms firm ]
breed [ consumers consumer ]
firms-own [ price ]
hogus-own [ money stock ]
globals [ m0 ]
```

There are also 100 customers, and 10 firms.  The price of the firms is set randomly from 0 to 10, and each consumer has an initial capital of 100.

```
to setup
  set m0 [ 0 ]
  set m0 lput p0 m0
end

to go
tick
buy
sell
set m0 fput p0 m0  
end 

to-report p0 
  report [ price ] of one-of firms 
end 

to-report recent 
  report item ticks m0 
end 

to-report past 
  report item ( ticks - 1 ) m0 
end
```

I've made a list so I can compare the current and past prices of the firm, however I've run into a problem.  I want each agent to choose a random 5 firms, and then compare the past and current price.  Then, if the price has increase the consumer should buy it (i.e. increase stock).  I tried to do it this way

```
to buy 
  if (recent > past and capital > 0) [ 
    set capital  capital - recent0 
    set stock stock + 1 ] 
end
```

but I'm running into an issue.  Each agent should choose their own, random firm.  However because every agent is bound by the same code, they always buy from the same firm.  How could I resolve this?

Comment: You have a lot of moving pieces here, and the question is unclear. It is too hard to extract a single question from this.  Here are some possible questions you could ask.  How can I have a customer look at 5 random firms. (Answer: use `n-of`.)  How can I track the price histories of all 10 firms? (Answer: use the `table` extension.)   How can I have a customer hold a portfolio of stocks instead of just an aggregate?  (Answer: use a list.)  Etc.